# Fullscreen background image not scrolling with content html5 phonegap

Tags: android, css, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a fullpage background image with following code:

```
<html class="full" lang="en">
    <body class="full" >    
             header, footer and content.... Extending beyond the initial view.
        </body>
</html>

<style>   
.full {
  background: transparent url(../img/blur-background.jpg)  no-repeat 0 0 fixed; 

  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

My problem description is,

- Initially the full screen background image is rendered in the android phone. [NO PROBLEM]
- But when I scroll, the background image is not appearing. Instead white background appears. [ISSUE]
- The original background re-appears **only** if I click some control in the view. In my case, the checkbox. [ISSUE]

Below are the screens

**Original - Full Screen background**

[image: Original - Full Screen]

**Partial White background on scroll**

[image: White background on scroll]

**Screen background appearing after scroll. Notice that the original background is not extended. The background image starts/repeats again.**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the issue by using CSS and jQuery. Now it works perfectly.

**mypage.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/full-screen.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/full-screen.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" data-cache="false">
    <div data-role="header">
    </div>
    <div  class="ui-content"  data-role="content">

        <!-- All content here....... Scrollable content here.... -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

**full-screen.css**

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: none;
    background-attachment:fixed;  
    border: 0px;
}


.ui-page {
    background-color: #373737 !important; /*Any color based on the data-theme selected*/
}

.ui-content {
    background: transparent url(../img/blur-background.jpg);
    background-size : 100% 100%;
}
```

**full-screen.js**

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function(){
     SizeContent();
});
$(window).on("resize orientationchange", function(){
    SizeContent();
});

function SizeContent(){
    var screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight();
    var header = $(".ui-header").hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-header").outerHeight();
    var footer = $(".ui-footer").hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer").outerHeight();
    var contentCurrent = $(".ui-content").outerHeight() - $(".ui-content").height();
    var content = screen - header - footer - contentCurrent;
    $(".ui-content").height(content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an explicit div for your background, e.g. :

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="homeScreenBG"></div>
<div id="restOfPage">
             header, footer and content.... Extending beyond the initial view.
</div>
        </body>
</html>


#homeScreenBG {
position: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
    background-image: transparent url(../img/blur-background.jpg)  no-repeat 0 0 fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
}
```